# Text CLustering Algorithms

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, text-mining, text-analysis

I am looking to cluster a bunch of Twitter hashtags based on their topics. All the hashtags related to the same topic will go under the same cluster. I was looking for any python based libraries which popular and efficient. I would also like suggestions on which algorithms I should be considering to cluster them together.

Answer (score 1):

Good luck:
Twitter data is so messy, I doubt you will be able to get meaningful results.

Definitely try TF-IDF, and as many algorithms as you can get working on your data.

But what are you going to do with tweets such as this:

> Cool: #HashTagIMadeUpForYourSOQuestionASDAS

Which "topic" should this be? How would you expect a clustering algorithm to *meaningfully* cluster this?

Comment: Thank you. I know it is going to be hard to get meaningful results. But I want to group the meaningful hashtags into clusters. The rest I can put it in separate clusters. What algorithms should I look at and are there any tools which already tag the hashtags so that they can be clustered by the topics?

Comment: I'm not aware of an algorithm that IMHO gives satisfactory results. For a starter, compute how often tags are mentioned together, and use the strongly connected components. This is not found in "clustering" algorithms, but graph algorithms.

Comment: Okay will look into that. What other factors do you think I can consider?

Comment: You realize there's companies that do exactly this. The point of machine learning is to deal with "messy data."

Comment: Which doesn't imply it works well. People try it, but it only works for very particular use cases. Because it only works when you assume a lot of structure on your mess...

Answer (score 0):

I can recomend natural language processing in python (NLTK package). But as it was sad, it might be challanging with Twiter (but lots of fun too). Might I know, what are you need that for?;)